# Powershell: Counting members in a list of DistributionGroups

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Good day everyone.

I have the following code, all working and giving a list that format as it shows in the code

```
Name    | PrimarySmtpAddress     |  RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled
Group1    Group1@primarysmtp.com | false/true
```

```
Get-ADgroup -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties * | ForEach-Object { Get-DistributionGroup -Filter * -ResultSize Unlimited | select Id, Name, PrimarySmtpAddress, RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled | Export-Csv  C:\powershell\DistributionLists\SecurityGroups.csv -NoType -Append }
```

So far so good.
What i would like to do is to embed an additional column that will count all members and sub-memebrs of the group nested under the AD groups/Distribution groups i am listing.

im wrapping my head on how i can embed this:

```
" @{n='Members' ;e={(Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive ).Count}} "
```

or anything similar of sort into the code here so i will get the right Results.

Your help would be mostly appreciated!

Comment: What you want is a pivot table.  The rows are the members and the columns are the groups.  You want to enumerate through the rows and then add to each row the column(s) which the members belong to.  See my answer at following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75551467/powershell-script-list-certain-adgroups-as-column-headings-their-users-as-ro

Comment: Why start the code with `Get-ADgroup` and **never** use any of the results from that in the rest of the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you are starting your code wit a call to `Get-ADGroup` and pipe the results through but **never** use any of that.
If you want to get details of distribution groups or mail-enabled security groups, just use [Get-DistributionGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps) combined with [Get-DistributionGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps) in order to get the count of members of such a group.

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter * -ResultSize Unlimited | 
Select-Object Id, Name, PrimarySmtpAddress, RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled,
              @{Name = 'Members'; Expression = { @(Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -ResultSize Unlimited).Count }} |
Export-Csv -Path 'C:\powershell\DistributionLists\SecurityGroups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

As per your comment to also get a count of the members in nested groups, For that you need a recursive helper function like below:

```
 function Get-NestedDistributionGroupMembers([string]$Identity) {
    # parameter Identity: Name, Alias, DistinguishedName, CanonicalName, EmailAddress or GUID
    $groupMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Identity -ResultSize Unlimited
    foreach ($member in $groupMembers) {
        if ($member.RecipientTypeDetails -match "group") {
            # recurse if we've found a group
            Get-NestedDistributionGroupMembers $member.PrimarySmtpAddress
        }           
        else {
            $member
        }
    }
}

Get-DistributionGroup -Filter * -ResultSize Unlimited | 
Select-Object Id, Name, PrimarySmtpAddress, RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled,
              @{Name = 'Members'; Expression = { @(Get-NestedDistributionGroupMembers $_.PrimarySmtpAddress).Count }} |
Export-Csv -Path 'C:\powershell\DistributionLists\SecurityGroups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello Theo., the reason i am using Get-ADgroup is due to that i want the SEARCHBASE of the groups concentrate on a specific OU. can you advise of a better way to do this using the cmdlets you've mentioned? Also, will your cmdlts fetch "contacts" ?

Comment: I`m getting only  "0" (Zero`s) in the "Members" count column. any ideas ?

Comment: @sl1986 Could you try `Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.DistinguishedName` instead of `$_ | Get-DistributionGroupMember` ?

Comment: Dear Theo,

i did this.

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter * -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit $OUpath | 
Select-Object Id, Name, PrimarySmtpAddress, RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled,
              @{n="MemberCount";e={(Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -ResultSize Unlimited | measure ).Count}} |
Export-Csv -Path 'C:\powershell\DistributionLists\DistributionListsUnderSpecificOU2.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
```
Its counting, 
However, what i don't seem to the count of users nested under the nested n groups,  any ideas?

Comment: @sj1986 Please see my edit.I have added a recursive helper function to also get the members in nested groups

Comment: This took the cake. Thanks Theo, i appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add user counting functions to select:

```
Get-ADgroup -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties * | ForEach-Object { Get-DistributionGroup -Filter * -ResultSize Unlimited | select Id, Name, PrimarySmtpAddress, RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled, @{n='Members'; e={Get-ADGroupMember $_.Name -Recursive | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count}} | Export-Csv C:\powershell\DistributionLists\SecurityGroups.csv -NoType -Append }
```

Comment: Hey, how are you my friend? Great to have you on board !
This is pretty much what i was looking for to achieve here, HOWEVER,
One small additional challenge here.

The script doesn't include CONTACTS in the count ...
Infact it ignores them completely, i get 0 value if there are only contacts on the target group/distribution list.

Any idea howe can get CONTCATS to the count aswell ?

Comment: This will be more difficult because Get-ADGroupMember does not include contacts. I don't quite know how to use it with your infrastructure, but something like this command:
`Get-ADObject -Filter 'memberof -eq $distinguishednamegroup -and (objectClass -eq "user" -or ObjectClass -eq "contact")'`

Comment: How would you combine this with the syntax above? " Get-ADObject" will be set in place of  Get-ADgroup  ?

Comment: Replace members counting like `@{n='Members'; e={Get-ADObject -Filter 'memberof -eq $distinguishednamegroup -and (objectClass -eq "user" -or ObjectClass -eq "contact")'}`. I don't have any contact in AD so i can't test it.

Comment: Err ... that will come in place of counting? i dont see any counting related cmdlet here

Comment: Ya, sorry - ```@{n='Members'; e={(Get-ADObject -Filter 'memberof -eq $distinguishednamegroup -and (objectClass -eq "user" -or ObjectClass -eq "contact")').Count}``` and i think you can replace $distinguishednamegroup to $_.distinguishedname

Comment: Looks nice, only i think this would ignore what we previously did " Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count}} " so that the users that are nested in the sub-groups won't count. only the direct members/groups which are members. correct me if im wrong tough.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I think it's worth you to go back to Get-ADGroupMember and count users including subgroups, and write a separate script to count contacts and combine the data.
Alternatively, you can rewrite the script to count users and contacts by checking each group separately and using nested lists (or json, even better) to create a hierarchy. Then add them in a loop as scope level as you want. Of course, the whole script will be much longer, but it will be more scalable. I don't know any other way to count users and contacts at the same time and taking into account subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve used a combined solution from the answers below, the following syntax is what best worked out for me.

```
$OUpath = 'OU=Security Groups,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com'

{ Cmdlet for connecting to exchange on-premises on my company}

Get-DistributionGroup -Filter * -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit $OUpath | select Id, DistinguishedName, Name, PrimarySmtpAddress, @{n='Members'; e={(Get-ADGroupMember $_.DistinguishedName -Recursive).Count}}, RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled  | Export-Csv C:\powershell\DistributionLists\SecurityGroupsUnderSpecificOU.csv -NoType -Append
```